# TimeZone of CurrentThread

Tags: c#, timezone, terminal-services

As MSDN says, "TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone" returns the time zone of the current computer. What I want to have is the timezone of the current session/application.

Situation: We have a terminalserver with local timezone A, user comes from time zone B to this server. Through its profile the time zone will be set for the application on the terminal server, but not for the whole computer.

What I want to have is the response of "tzutil".

Does anybody know how to get it?

Comment: Sounds like: I am from TimeZone A and watching TV (TimeZone B). What I want, that my TV shows me my time.

Comment: Is your terminal server configured to use Time Zone Redirection? See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783386.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725887.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is no facility in .NET for setting the time zone of an application, process, session, or thread.  The "current time zone" is the one set by the time zone control panel or tzutil for the entire system.

However, since you said you are concerned with Terminal Services sessions, I assume you mean that you are using the [time zone redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783386.aspx) feature of Terminal services.  In this case, Terminal Services is swapping out or visualizing the registry keys that control the current system time zone.  So when you ask .NET for the current system time zone, it *should* already be the one controlled by Terminal Services, as long as you have enabled the time zone redirection feature.  You should test this in your environment.

Normally, without Terminal Services involved, If you need to track a specific user's time zone in your application, you should provide your own mechanism for the user to set their time zone.  You would store the ID of that time zone with the user's profile in your application.  You would then use that ID to retrieve the time zone for the user whenever you needed to convert values to that time zone.  This is the normal advice for web applications, and for thick-client client/server applications.  Terminal Services is a bit different, as explained above.

Also, you should be using the `TimeZoneInfo` class.  The `TimeZone` class only allows for working with the system's time zone or with UTC, and is essentially deprecated.  To get the current time zone, call `TimeZoneInfo.Local`.

You also asked how to "have the response of tzutil".  I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that, but I'll guess that you're probably looking for the `Id` and `DisplayName` properties of a `TimeZoneInfo` object.